# Warning:Dependency org.json:json:20090211 is ignored for debug as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android

Tags: android, json, android-studio, gradle, android-sdk-tools

I am getting below error while running Android studio.

> Warning:Dependency org.json:json:20090211 is ignored for debug as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.

my build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.1.0'
    compile 'org.java-websocket:Java-WebSocket:1.3.0'
    compile 'com.github.nkzawa:engine.io-client:0.6.0'
    compile 'com.github.nkzawa:socket.io-client:0.6.0'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
    compile files('libs/json_simple.jar')
    compile files('libs/pushy-1.0.7.jar')
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.7.0'
}
```

I tried excluding org.json,it is not working.

```
exclude group:'org.json',module:'json'
```

but when i remove socket.io-client,engine.io-client and facebook sdk

android studio is running without warnings.

please tell where am i going wrong,

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

**Try this once again. it will definitely work.**

You can exclude json dependency from the module by adding the following lines in your build.gradle

**I changed from this**

```
compile 'com.github.nkzawa:socket.io-client:0.4.1'
```

**to**

```
compile ('com.github.nkzawa:socket.io-client:0.4.1'){
exclude group: 'org.json', module: 'json'
}
```

This worked for me : no warning anymore :)